# C++ Assert Macro that report failure value

Tags: c++, assert

I have tons of run time assertion failure in my application and I need to sit with each one to find out what is the run time value of the assert conditions that results such a failure. For example:

```
assert ( a == b ) ;
```

in line number 100 failed. in run time, I can only see that some thing happen in line number 100 then, I need to set a break point there to find out actual value of a and b.

My questions is that is there any way to get more intelligent failure report more than line numbers? I would like to see value of variables that are mismatch.

Comment: A normal debugger will break on an assertion failure. From there, you can search to get the values rather than going through the run, set BP, re-run procedure,

Comment: Have a look at the [CATCH test framework](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch). I haven't got round to figuring out exactly how it works yet, but it does exactly what you describe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize the language to define your own assert macros of course:

```
#define ASSERT_EQUAL(a,b) if ((a) != (b)) std::cout << "Assertion failed:" << (a) << "!=" << (b) << " at:" << __LINE__
```

However, I would argue that if you're relying excesively on assertions, you might want to express some of thes "exceptional" errors as exceptions. A good debugger will catch these and describe the exception by name. You may have something more meaningful to say rather than `a != b`, for example:

```
if (a != b) {
    throw InvalidArgumentsException(a, b);
}
```

While this is useful, its important to realize than exceptions get thrown in both debug and release builds while assertions typically only get run in debug builds.

Comment: Nitpicks: all the usages of `a` and `b` should be parenthesized and the macro should be [wrapped](http://c-faq.com/cpp/multistmt.html) in a `do {} while(0)` block.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a debugger? A good debugger tells you what you need to know.

Comment: Because I need to re-run the application to the same point at get the values. I have tons of these lines and in does make no sense to re-run application for every one.

Comment: Think of all that work as a lesson: you wrote too much code before you started testing.

Answer (score 0):

I released [`PPK_ASSERT`](https://github.com/gpakosz/Assert). Example usage:

```
#include <pempek_assert.h>

int main()
{
  float min = 0.0f;
  float max = 1.0f;
  float v = 2.0f;
  PPK_ASSERT(v > min && v < max, "invalid value: %f, must be between %f and %f", v, min, max);

  return 0;
}
```